# AutoCAD - missing icons in Tool Palettes

Tags: autocad

I have a problem with my Tool Palettes. Currently tried several methods, which unfortunately didn't bring the desired result.
The situation looks as follows:

[image]

After loading the palette from the file (.acx extension) I have just a blank box instead of a proper signature. Moreover, I don't know why my Tool Properties are inactive. Therefore I can't use this option at all:

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2021/ENU/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-021B36D2-5009-43FE-A78C-E4BE8EED0960-htm.html

I have got AutoCAD LT 2020, so after trying the following options:

1. Finding the following address and putting the .acx palettes there:
   https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-import-tool-palette-atc-files-into-AutoCAD-Plant-3D.html
2. Customizing the interface as shown here
   https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Palettes-will-not-display-in-AutoCAD.html
   https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Palettes-will-not-display-in-AutoCAD.html
3. Manual export & import layers didn't help

Could anyone advise what to do? I am quite fresh user to AutoCAD

Comment: I recommend you try specific Autocad support forums like the link below, as an example.
https://www.eng-tips.com/threadminder.cfm?pid=555

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you seek is called a "Profile" and can be exported/imported as a .arg file.

File->Options then Profiles tab.

My recollection may be outdated, but they likely still call it a "Profile"

Answer (score 0):

Your palette is locked for writing. See the padlock at the bottom. Most probably this is because the files/folders are set as read only in your operating system.

Can't tell why your icons are not displayed properly though